# using FileStream to read file, will it be blocking?

Tags: scala

So in Scala, when I use the java filestream lib like:

```
inStream = Option(new FileInputStream(file))
  ..
  in.read(imageData)
  Some(imageData)
```

will this cause a blocking operation? in another word, should this be wrapped in a Future to make it asynchronous?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a blocking operation.

Wrapping it in a `Future` won't make the file operation asynchronous, but it *will* tie up a thread from the `Future` executor service / thread pool...

**Addendum**

All execution in the JVM occurs on a thread. When one uses a `Future` the thread on which the encapsulated computations occurs is distinct from the one that initiated that `Future`. When you use the old `java.io` the operations are blocking, whether you call them directly or hand them off to a `Future`.

If the intention is to create high-concurrency systems, one does no blocking operations at all. Using `Future` and actors allow you to achieve high concurrency without the high overhead of a thread-per I/O operation *but only if the I/O operations themselves are non-blocking*.

Comment: Randall is right. We have a class that abstracts this fact away so I'd forgotten about this.  I've deleted my answer as it was incorrect.  Simply wrapping in a future won't make it async, you'll need special logic for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I am not clear what it means though, " but it will tie up a thread from the Future executor service / thread pool..." can you explain a bit more?

Comment: also, is this is not working, what is the right way to do async file io operation in scala?

Comment: [scala-io](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/overview) is a project that wraps java6/7 NIO in scala, which is actually non blocking. I think it's relatively stable, otherwise you should use directly java NIO. The future solution is still blocking, because it frees the *current thread* from waiting for the future response, but still spawns and occupies *another* thread to do the actual (blocking) computation. The subtle difference is that asynchronous and blocking are not exactly the same thing. It's about considering the calling thread only, or the whole system.